# My node.js Server is running successfully in heroku but build failed.( Timeout running buildpack)

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, oauth-2.0, nodemailer

enter image description here

I have attached all the environment variables at heroku and pulled the code from github. After that i have tried to deploy the app. It run’s well but build fails. [image](Github project link -> https://github.com/shubhamGhosh-dev/OAuth-messaging-server)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After two days of struggle, I found the issue. Which is just a script (`"build" : "node index.js"`) in `package.json` file.

After removing `"build" : "node index.js"`, the app is deployed successfully. But still curious for this behaviour.